# Docker commit of working container to new image, then create container with new image fails

Tags: docker

I am using the docker container generated from building the angular-seed-advanced seed project. The container runs perfectly locally, and wanted to create an image from it so I can deploy to azure.

When I commit the container to a new image, and then attempt to docker create newImage up I get

```
" cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2b595d7cbdeaba17e5f0ad17011c28819bedac789379f4fb2829c53f5d0323d0/merged/etc/nginx/conf.d/angular-seed.template"
```

Googling this error so far has not been helpful. Is the flow I am attempting not valid? Seems like the whole point of docker is to avoid weird stuff like this on such a simple flow.

Comment: which version of docker do you have?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72

Comment: Share the details so I can try and build on my machine

Comment: What details will be helpful? I am cloning this repo

https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced

Using the prod docker commands from the readme to get my working container

Doing "docker commit existing-container newImage" to commit the working container to an image

Then "docker create newImage up" throws the error